# Internal error in jsf

Tags: google-maps, jsf

I use jsf to show a googlemap like this

```
    <f:view contentType="text/html">        
        <p:gmap id="gmap" center="41.381542, 2.122893" zoom="15" type="ROADMAP"   
        style="width:600px;height:400px"  
        model="#{restaurant.emptyModel}"   
        onPointClick="handlePointClick(event);"   
        widgetVar="map" /></f:view>
    <h:inputHidden id="lat" value="#{restaurant.lat}" />  
    <h:inputHidden id="lng" value="#{restaurant.lng}" />  
    <h:commandButton value="Add" 
               action="#{restaurant.submitInfo}"/>
```

When i delete tag `<h:commandButton>` , an error ocured:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Property 'submitInfo' not found on type sig.Restaurant
javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:325)
sig.CharsetFilter.doFilter(CharsetFilter.java:25)
```

I don't know how to solve it, thank for helping.

Comment: Can you provide the complete page source ? And possibly the managed-bean method `submitInfo()` ?

Comment: @kocko this is complete page source
[html](http://pastebin.com/HR7MaZY7)
and this is submitInfo java source:
[java](http://pastebin.com/q9qkbug0)